# How to save user input data to XML according to MVVM

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have tried to search and read many articles but I still don't understand how to work with MVVM in my example. I have got a page with two textboxes (like `Name` and `Description`),one `ListPicker` and save button. I guess model will be like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Enum Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Now I don't know how to concept ViewModel (and maybe View). I wanna save that data (filled by user) to XML file and later have list of saved MyItems on another page and show details after click but I hope I can do this later.
I know how to work with XML data, I just don't know how to use ViewModel for saving non-hardcoded data.

Thanks for help and explanation.

**EDIT:**

```
    public class MyItemViewModel
{

    public MyItemViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveToXml());
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }


    private Action<object> SaveToXml()
    {
    // Saving data to XML
    }
}
```

Error: MyItemViewModel.SaveToXml()': not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is bind to the Command property of the Button, then set up an ICommand property in your ViewModel:

Lets say this is your button, which is bound by DataContext to your ViewModel

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Command="{Binding MyButtonClickCommand}" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"/>
```

What you have to do now is go to your ViewModel and add a property of type **[`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.icommand)**:

```
public ICommand MyButtonClickCommand { get; private set; }
```

I usually like to set the command via the constructor using a concrete command called [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx):

```
public MyClass()
{
   MyButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(YourMethodWhichSavesToXml);
}
```

and then, just create a method which is responsible for saving your XML to the disk (Change the location inside the `XmlTextWriter` to your phones correct location):

```
private void YourMethodWhichSavesToXml()
{
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyItem));
   using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\mylocation", Encoding.UTF8))
   {
      serializer.Serialize(writer, _MyItem);    
   }
}
```

**Edit**

Your ViewModel should have all the properties you want to bind to inside your view.
Lets say you to have a list of MyItems which you want to bind to your ListView, then it could look like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(YourMethodWhichSavesToXml());
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

    public MyItem MySelectedItem { get; set; }

    private void YourMethodWhichSavesToXml()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyItem));
        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\mylocation", Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, MySelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure that "C:\mylocation" exists on Windows Phone ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks, but could you also outline how my viewmodel could look like?

Comment: Added a viewmodel outline :)

Comment: And what about this?
The type or namespace name 'DelegateCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry but I can't try that right now because I am at school and I would need administrator rights for installation of this. Is there any other way to do that without external packages or tools?
I assume it will work though but I still don't understand where is defined how is user data read for YourMethodWhichSavesToXml method?

Comment: You can implement DelegateCommand yourself, there are alot of examples on the web, just look and see how they do it, its really not that difficult. The user data can read with binding from your XAML to your ViewModel

Comment: I added the ListView binding to the example, hope that helps

Comment: Ok, so I implmented this one
http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html
And problem is with YourMethodWhichSavesToXml method - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Action' to 'System.Action<object>'
If I change void to Action, then is "not all code paths return value".

Comment: Make YourMethod like this: YourMethodWhichSavesToXml(object obj)

Comment: This:
public MyViewModel()
{
     SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(YourMethodWhichSavesToXml(MyItems));
}

private Action<object> YourMethodWhichSavesToXml(object obj)
{
 //saving data to xml...
}
gives again not all code paths return a value...
Anyway, honestly, I'm sorry, I appreciate your help with this way but I would probably prefer another "more common and understandable way" here to do that, without  Command property and "external methods". It will  be nice if this work but I feel like this way is not giving me proper MVVM knowledge...

Comment: I suggest you go ahead an read some tutorials about MVVM. i think you are missing some of the fundamentals which are critical to you writing  proper working code. good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will, but could we at least get this thing working for now? I edited main post.